# Implementing Session Logs in a P2P Crypto Exchange with Node.js or Nest.js

Tags: node.js, session, logging, nest, google-cloud-logging

Body:

I am currently working on building a P2P Crypto Exchange, and I'm looking to implement session logs in the security section. These logs should capture data such as** Date & Time, IP Address, Location, Device, and Operating System.
**

I am using Node.js and considering Nest.js for the project. Can anyone provide guidance or examples on how to achieve this kind of session logging in a secure and efficient manner? Are there any specific libraries or best practices I should be aware of?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

We try multiple solution but failed.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.